fetching rows from db that are selected by dropbar
guys i wrote a dropdown bar connected to a db, but i couldnt  make the content of the table thats fetched from db only specified by the option i chose in drop bar, how can i fix this
here's my code:
$sql = "SELECT CPTE FROM comana";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql); 

oci_execute($stmt);

while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>" . ($row['CPTE'] !== null ? htmlentities($row['CPTE'], ENT_QUOTES) : '') . "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
    echo "</table>\n";

i want the table to only fetch the selected option data

It looks like your SQL statement retrieves all the records in the comana table. Do you have any code for retrieving what value is selected in the list-box (if that's what a "drop bar" is). If you're asking how to filter the value, you will need to decide whether to add a criterion to your SQL statement or instead to filter rows in your while-loop.
